# Location of Desktop Shell Folder

Tags: batch-file

Is there any code or parameter to specify the desktop file on a user's computer, but is also compatible on other users in a batch file?

Or here's an example. Here's a code

```
move -y temp.bat [The parameter I'm asking for]
```

I'm asking if there is a parameter that can be used to specify the Desktop on both A's computer:

```
C:\Users\A\Desktop
```

And B's computer:

```
C:\Users\B\Desktop
```

Thanks.

Comment: `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` generally works (there could be some folder-redirection scenario where it doesn't - no promises).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has the means of accessing Shell Folders (via the [registry](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962613.aspx) or [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx)) so that any application that wants to can find it.

Here's how it can be obtained using [PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/02/20/the-easy-way-to-use-powershell-to-work-with-special-folders.aspx).

```
SETLOCAL

FOR /F "usebackq" %%f IN (`PowerShell -NoProfile -Command "Write-Host([Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop'))"`) DO ( SET "DESKTOP_FOLDER=%%f" )

@ECHO %DESKTOP_FOLDER%
```

Comment: So, do I directly insert this code into my batch file, or do I create a new file? Where should I insert then?

Comment: The `FOR /F` statement is all you really must insert into your existing script. It set the env var `DESKTOP_FOLDER` so that you can use it elsewhere in the script.

Comment: So where should I insert it? (Sorry it seems dumb but I am just a sort of beginner)

Comment: Any point before you actually need to know where the desktop folder is. In the example you provided, before the `move` command, which should look something like this: `move -y temp.bat "%DESKTOP_FOLDER%"`

Comment: Okey! Thanks for the advice. My batch can now find the desktop automatically.

Comment: I need 15Rep, I only got 10Rep. I'll definitely upvote this answer when I get 15. ;)

Comment: As a matter of general principle, add `tokens=* delims=`, i.e. `FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %f IN ...` for _what-if_ result contains a space