# Get the Windows Download folder's path (Download shell folder) in a batch-file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

How do I get the Windows Download Shell Folder in a variable?

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901817/location-of-desktop-shell-folder). I tried:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

FOR /F "usebackq" %%f IN (`PowerShell -NoProfile -Command "Write-Host([Environment]::GetFolderPath('{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}'))"`) DO ( SET "DOWNLOAD_FOLDER=%%f" )

@ECHO %DOWNLOAD_FOLDER%
pause
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: What's wrong with `%userprofile%\Downloads`?

Comment: Let me doubt the PowerShell `GetFolderPath` method allows a GUID as a valid argument. Says: The possible enumeration values are "Desktop, Programs, Personal, MyDocuments, Favorites, Startup, Recent, SendTo, StartMenu, MyMusic, DesktopDirectory, MyComputer, Templates, ApplicationData, LocalApplicationData, InternetCache, Cookies, History, CommonApplicationData, System, ProgramFiles, MyPictures, CommonProgramFiles". And default value for your [folder GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx) is `%USERPROFILE%\Downloads`

Comment: Thanks. It was just aa try to use the GUID. Because it was on the "Shell Folders" too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a batch code to get several directories for downloads which I think is self-explaining.

This batch code was tested only on Windows XP x86 with Internet Explorer 8.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "Reg32=%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe"
if not "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "" set "Reg32=%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\reg.exe"

set "DownloadDirectory="
for /F "skip=4 tokens=3*" %%U in ('%Reg32% query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v "Download Directory" 2^>nul') do (
    set "DownloadDirectory=%%V"
    goto GetSaveDir
)

:GetSaveDir
set "SaveDirectory="
for /F "skip=4 tokens=3*" %%U in ('%Reg32% query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "Save Directory" 2^>nul') do (
    set "SaveDirectory=%%V"
    goto OutputResults
)

:OutputResults
cls
echo/

echo Download directory of user account is:
echo/
echo    %USERPROFILE%\Downloads
echo/
echo/

if not defined DownloadDirectory goto OutputSaveDir
if "%DownloadDirectory:~-1%" == "\" set "DownloadDirectory=%DownloadDirectory:~0,-1%"
echo Download directory of Internet Explorer is:
echo/
echo    %DownloadDirectory%
echo/
echo/

:OutputSaveDir
if not defined SaveDirectory goto EndBatch
if "%SaveDirectory:~-1%" == "\" set "SaveDirectory=%SaveDirectory:~0,-1%"
echo Save directory of Internet Explorer is:
echo/
echo    %SaveDirectory%

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

**UPDATE**

But for Windows Vista/7/8/8.1/10 an enhanced batch file is needed as the directory for downloads is defined different on those later Windows versions with Internet Explorer 8/9/10/11.

The batch code below works on all Windows OS starting with Windows 2000.

It outputs the directories found on hard disk (first one) or in Windows registry (remaining three).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "Reg32=%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe"
if not "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "" set "Reg32=%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\reg.exe"

set "DownloadShellFolder="
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2*" %%T in ('%Reg32% query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}" 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%T" == "{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}" (
        set "DownloadShellFolder=%%V"
        goto GetDownloadDirectory
    )
)

:GetDownloadDirectory
set "DownloadDirectory="
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3*" %%S in ('%Reg32% query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer" /v "Download Directory" 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%S" == "Download" (
        if /I "%%T" == "Directory" (
            set "DownloadDirectory=%%V"
            goto GetSaveDirectory
        )
    )
)

:GetSaveDirectory
set "SaveDirectory="
for /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3*" %%S in ('%Reg32% query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "Save Directory" 2^>nul') do (
    if /I "%%S" == "Save" (
        if /I "%%T" == "Directory" (
            set "SaveDirectory=%%V"
            goto OutputResults
        )
    )
)

:OutputResults
cls
echo/

if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads" goto OutputShellFolder
echo Download directory of user account is:
echo/
echo   %USERPROFILE%\Downloads
echo/
echo/

:OutputShellFolder
if not defined DownloadShellFolder goto OutputDownloadDir
if "%DownloadShellFolder:~-1%" == "\" set "DownloadShellFolder=%DownloadShellFolder:~0,-1%"
echo Download shell folder of user account is:
echo/
echo   %DownloadShellFolder%
echo/
echo/

:OutputDownloadDir
if not defined DownloadDirectory goto OutputSaveDir
if "%DownloadDirectory:~-1%" == "\" set "DownloadDirectory=%DownloadDirectory:~0,-1%"
echo Download directory of Internet Explorer is:
echo/
echo   %DownloadDirectory%
echo/
echo/

:OutputSaveDir
if not defined SaveDirectory goto EndBatch
if "%SaveDirectory:~-1%" == "\" set "SaveDirectory=%SaveDirectory:~0,-1%"
echo Save directory of Internet Explorer is:
echo/
echo   %SaveDirectory%

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `cls /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `reg /?`
- `reg query /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: On my W8.1 x64 Dutch machine. I just get one result:
_Download shell folder of user account is:
e:\Downloads_ that's right.

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand what all the nonsense is about.

Just use `%userprofile%\Downloads`.

Comment: non-english OS might use a different path, for example `%userprofile%\téléchargements`. also, the user may change it to wherever they want, for example `E:\Stuff`

Comment: A user has the freedom to change the folder for downloads with just a few mouse clicks. The internet browsers like Internet Explorer. Microsoft Edge, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Opera, Safari, etc. take the user´s configuration for the downloads folder into account which is good as on none of my Windows computers exists the folder `%userprofile%\Downloads` at all. I have configured the folder for downloads on a different drive which helps together with other user configurations keeping clean the system drive as I use a separate drive for all types of temporary files.

Comment: ❌ ```%userprofile%\Downloads``` does **NOT** work if the user has changed the folder location in properties -- Following the comments above (and confirming explicitly after testing), I had changed the location to [D:\Downloads] and got an 'could not find the specified path' error when I tried %userprofile%\Downloads... So in terms of "*not understanding what the **nonsense** is about*"; what the OP and people like myself want is a **safe** way to always reference the user's CSLID downloads folder, wherever it resides.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried something like this in PS
(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:Downloads').Self.Path

Answer (score 1):

#### 1-line cmd

`FOR /f "tokens=3" %%Z in ('Reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /v "{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}" ^|findstr /i "REG_"') do SET Downloads=%%Z`

The above uses the entry in the 'User Shell Folders' registry and sets this to the variable 'Downloads' which you can then use / reference in your script. Tested on Windows 10, 11.